# Destroying a member object

Tags: c++, css, memory-management, destructor

I want to release the memory of the object that is defined in the class

```
class A
{
     A() {} //Constructor
    //Other Definitions go here
}

Class B
{
   B(){} //Constructor
   ~B()
{
   //what should I do to release the memory location of A's object
   //Shall I call default destructor of A 
}
private:
A objA;
}
```

Comment: Doing nothing is best.

Comment: It's going to be automatically released unless you dynamically allocated it with `new` (in that case, you'll need to `delete` it).

Comment: A's destructor will automatically be called.

Comment: You do not have any derived classes in your code.

Comment: There is no base class - you contain a class

Comment: Actually I am running my code Multiple times(in an Infinite Loop) so when it is run second time and I print the address of the object objA It is taking the previous address only that's why I want to manually delete it in the destructor

Comment: @Euler, Believe us, if you touch anything about `objA`'s destruction, your code will gain undefined behaviour before you can say that.

Comment: What's wrong with the system using the address of a previously existing object? Why is that a problem for you?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything to release the memory occupied by `objA` in class `B`. The memory is automatically released when the memory of the `B` object is released.

You cannot do anything to release the memory occupied by `objA` in class `B` without destroying the `B` object that contains `objA`.

You can call the destructor of `objA` explicitly, but that does not release any memory. It merely leads to undefined behaviour when you access `objA` afterwards. And most likely `objA` *will* be accessed afterwards, because when the C++ runtime destroys the `B` object, it will call the destructor of `objA`.